# how to call function to modify a variable vba

Tags: vba, function, excel

What my code does is it takes a value froma nother workbook and copies and paste it in another workbook. What I want now however is a something that would remove the last 3 figures to have a final number in thousand dollars instead of dollars.

It would work fine if I were to build my function around my "DSA.Worksheet.Value..." but it would take time because I have quite a few of those. 
When I call my function on the DSA.worksheet cell it doesnt work, even if I call it like that:

```
Call number_right (DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round    (hello.Worksheets("getthis"").Range("I72").Value, -3)



Sub test()    
DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(hello.Worksheets("getthis").Range("I72").Value, -3)

DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10").Value = Call number_right(DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10").Value)

End Sub


Function number_right(n As Variant) As Variant
If Len(n) > 3 Then n = Left((n), Len(n) - 3)
End Function
```

Comment: The way you have written that, you are passing either True or False to the function, not a number. At a wild guess, you meant: `DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10").Value = number_right(Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(hello.Worksheets("getthis"").Range("I72").Value, -3))`

Comment: If I change my code to yours it does not display anything.. strange !

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. It needs to be: `If Len(n) > 3 Then number_right = Left((n), Len(n) - 3) else number_right = n`

Comment: Great! We're almost there I think... This line however: 
        `number_right = Left((i), Len(i) - 3)`  does not seem to work properly, as I dont think Len(i)-3 is recognized (it works if I replace it with the length manually. Do you know if there is a solution ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
Sub test()

Dim DSA As Workbook
Dim rngValue As Range

Set DSA = ActiveWorkbook  'May need to change this line if DSA is not already open
Set rngValue = DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10")

Set rngValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(hello.Worksheets("getthis").Range("I72").Value, -3)
If Len(rngValue) > 3 Then
    Set rngValue = number_right(rngValue)
End If

End Sub

Function number_right(n As Range) As Variant
    number_right = Left(n, Len(n) - 3)    
End Function
```

Comment: I get the error "ByRef argument type mismatch" on the last rngValue (If Len(rngValue) > 3 Then
    rngValue = number_right(ERROR HERE)
End If, would you know why that is?

Comment: @lo1ngru I changed the variable `n` to type `Range`. See if that works.

Comment: same error still. It may have to do with how I am writing my function I think !